# How am I calculating expected value wrong?

Tags: probability

So I'm trying to calculate the expected value of someone who plays this game.  Since it's fair for everyone, the expected value for an individual should be 0.  Yet, I'm getting a negative value - not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**Game Set Up**

There are 3 players.  The buy in is 5 dollars.  The winner of the game takes the entire pot.

Each person rolls a die once.  The person with the highest roll is the winner.  If there is a tie for the highest roll, the game resets and everyone plays again.

**What I Did**

To figure out the expected outcome for an individual, I broke down the probability of winning/losing/tying for each dice roll.

The probability of rolling any number is 1/6 or 16.67%.

The probability of rolling:

(p<6) = 83%

(p<5) = 67%

(p<4) = 50%

(p<3) = 33%

(p<2) = 17%

(p<1) = 0%

---

(p>6) = 0%

(p>5) = 17%

(p>4) = 33%

(p>3) = 50%

(p>2) = 67%

(p>1) = 83%

---

With this we can calculate the outcomes of winning/losing/tying.

Odds of winning if you roll a 6:
(p=6) * (p<6) * (p<6) = 12%

Odds of losing if you roll a 6:
(p=6) * (p>6)^2 + (p=6) * (p>6) * (1 - (p>6)) * 2 = 0%

Odds of tying if you roll a 6:
(p=6)^3 + (p=6)^2 * (p<6) * 2 = 5%

---

After calculating the probability of win/lose/tie for each die value, I add up the values to get:

(P winning) = 25%

(P losing) = 58%

(P tying) = 17%

Since tying resets the game, we can just make the probabilities:

(P winning) = 25/(25/58) = 31%

(P losing) = 69%

If you lose, you pay 5 dollars.  If you win, you make 10 dollars.  Thus the expected value is:

31% * 10 + 69% * -5 = -0.42

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the symmetry, once ties are excluded, the chance of winning must be $\frac 13\approx 33.33333\%$ and the chance of losing must be $\frac 23\approx 66.6667\%.$  You are showing $31-69$.  This looks to be caused by the fact that you round to whole percents throughout the calculation.

Comment: Hello,  I did my calculations in excel so I did not round.  I only rounded when writing this question to save time.

Comment: You haven't shown enough detail to know what is wrong.  What you say is "odds of winning if you roll a 6" is really "odds that both you roll a 6 and win", but $12\%$ is close.  The probability of a tie is $\frac 1{36}$ (that all three match)+$\frac 12 3\frac 16 \frac 56$ (that the high two match) $=\frac {17}{72} \approx 23.6\%$, the probability of a win is about $25.5\%$ and a loss is about $51\%$.